# UIView Rotation using swift issue

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I would like to rotate UIView which defined on the storyboard I used

```
CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: self.degreesToRadians(5))
```

which degreesToradians a function to convert to Radians, the rotation is working perfectly but the only problem is the UIView not vectorial (the edge of the view is not rendered properly and it looks like a saw) like in the screenshot below :

[image]

Comment: Pl. share more detail about your problem ("UIView not vectorial")

Comment: thanks @Krunal for your answer I've edited my question with more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have had the same problems as you and to solve it I just add a border to the view which is transparent, do it like this:

```
customView.layer.borderWidth = 1
customView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor // important that it is clear
customView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
customView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
```

Add that code after your `rotation` code.

With the code:
[image]

Without the code:
[image]

Comment: thanks @ Rashwan L 
in fact I need it to add just 

layer.shouldRasterize = true 

an dit worked perfectly  we don't need to use transparent border.

Comment: It seems to persist if I try to take a screenshot of the container view though it does solves the issue in a simulator/device, thanks